# android -what approach to be used for some java code that repeats in many activities

Tags: java, android

I have an app that has a top menu as shown in the fig below. This is almost constantly used in all activities. For layout I have defined it in a single xml file and use `<include>`to include it in every layout file.I want to know if there is a way in java coding to avoid declaring all the imageButtons, and then using `findViewById` and `onclick` events for them , in each activity. The top four icons will act as menu and be available in all layouts and activities [image]

Comment: Use inheritance.How about defining a base class with common code and make you all activities extend this class?

Comment: you can use tab bar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have accepted an answer I disagree that the Application class should be used to host global methods. It can be used for maintaining global state but that's a different matter.

As others have said, use inheritance by creating a base Activity class then extend that for all of your other Activities. To make things easier, however, you can define the onClick method to be used for each of your buttons in the layout file itself by using (for example)...

```
android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"
```

As long as the base Activity defines a public method called myOnClickMethod (or whatever method name you choose) with a void return and which accepts a View parameter it will work without the need to implement View.OnClickListener and without having to set the listener in Java code. Example

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public void myOnClickMethod(View v) {
        // Get the resource id of v and use switch / case to perform action needed
    }
}
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are trying to achieve is against the android standards and this could affect the user experience for Android users. Instead, add the menu items on the action bar.

Anyway, you can achieve what you are looking for by defining a base class (named it like `ActivityBase`) and do all the initializations and listeners registrations on it. Then, extend from that base class. Bear in mind that each activity will have its own instance of the views of the base class and the state will differ from activity to another.

Answer (score 1):

Write it only in the first activity. Extend it to the other activities instead of extending with `android.app.Activity`.

Eg:

```
public class SecondActivity extends MainActivity{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that method in MyApplication class which extends Application. So, that it can be accessible by multiple activities.